# How to display contents of array in view in ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

How do you display the contents of an array in a view?

In HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;

Show *show = [self.shows objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
ShowContentItem *showItem = show.showContentItems[indexPath.row];

if( [segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"Headline_Section"] ) {        
    HeadlinesViewController *headlinesVC = (HeadlinesViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    headlinesVC.shows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:show, nil];
} else {
    NSInteger contentIndex = [self.storyPostContent indexOfObject:showItem];
    NSRange rangeForView = NSMakeRange(contentIndex, [self.storyPostContent count] - contentIndex );

    ShowContentViewController *showContentVC = (ShowContentViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    showContentVC.contentList = [self.storyPostContent subarrayWithRange: rangeForView];
}

}
```

I want to display showContentVC.contentList in ShowContentViewController

Comment: Please add more details. There are a lot of options to display data: table views, labels, text fields, etc.

Comment: I want to display each element in the array as a label.

Answer (score 2):

In `ShowContentViewController`, probably in `viewDidLoad`, create a loop which iterates over the `contentList` array.

For each item in the array, create a label. Set the `frame` and `[self.view addSubview:...];`. Increment a variable for the `y` position of the frame so the next label is below the current one. Set some text on the label.